# how to use MKAnnotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview, iphone-developer-program

i have some problem when use `MKAnnotation`,
I want to add a Annotation on a MapView
so I create a class named `AdoptingAnAnnotation`,
the `.h` file follow
    #import 
    #import

```
@interface  AdoptingAnAnnotation: NSObject {
}

@synthesize latitude; 
@synthesize longitude;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
- (NSString *) title;
- (NSString *) subtitle;
@end
```

and .m file is follow

```
#import "AdoptingAnAnnotation.h"

@implementation AdoptingAnAnnotation

@synthesize latitude;
@synthesize longitude;

- (id) initWithLatitude:(CLLocationDegrees) lat longitude:(CLLocationDegrees) lng {
    latitude = lat;
    longitude = lng;
    return self;
   }
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {self.latitude, self.longitude};
    return coord;
    }
- (NSString *) title {
    return @"217 2nd St";
    }
- (NSString *) subtitle {
    return @"San Francisco CA 94105";
    }
@end
```

Get the error message like `illegal interface qualifier`
Is my syntax error or other error about the `MKAnnotation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@synthesize` statements belong in the class implementation, not in the interface. This is why you get the "illegal interface qualifier" error. Finally, your class should adopt the MKAnnotation protocol.

Comment: but when i remove the @synthesize from the .h file i get a other error message like http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/haibo/temp/Screen%20Shot%202012-02-25%20at%202.08.54%20PM.png this mean i should declaration some thing

Comment: If you're going to @synthesize `lattitude` and `longitude`, you'll need @property declarations for those in your @interface. Likewise, since you've got a @property declaration for `coordinate`, you should also either have a @synthesize directive for that property, or you should provide the accessors yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You posted your .h twice... edit please. Also you have synthesizers in your .h, they belong in .m. And make sure you implement those MKAnnotation methods.